# Datatable no responsive

Tags: datatables

Estoy tratando de hacer responsive una Datatable que recibe datos de servidor siguiendo el ejemplo de: https://coderexample.com/datatable-responsive-server-side/

Pero no veo que la tabla se convierta en responsive. No aparecen los botones + y mucho menos despliegan las columnas no visibles como el ejemplo.

> Creo que pueda ser por que uso `fnServerData` pero no estoy seguro.
>   ¿Como podría darle el aspecto responsive?

Aquí va el codigo:

```
{

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mytable').dataTable({

    responsive: {
        details: {
            renderer: function ( api, rowIdx ) {
            var data = api.cells( rowIdx, ':hidden' ).eq(0).map( function ( cell ) {
                var header = $( api.column( cell.column ).header() );
                return  '<p style="color:#00A">'+header.text()+' : '+api.cell( cell ).data()+'</p>';  // changing details mark up.
            } ).toArray().join('');

            return data ?    $('<table/>').append( data ) :    false;
            }

        }
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
         "sAjaxSource": "<?= site_url('admin/cp/ob_usu') ?>",
            "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            aoData.push({"name": "txt_b", "value": $('#txt_b').val()});
                    aoData.push({"name": "t_cli", "value": $('#t_cli').val()});
                    aoData.push({"name": "s_cr", "value": $('#s_cr').val()});
                    $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": aoData,
                            "success": fnCallback
                    });
            },
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ reg por pag",
                    "sZeroRecords": "Sin datos",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ reg",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 registros",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrando de _MAX_ registros totales)"
            },
            bStateSave: true,
    });


<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
...
   </table>
</div>

}
```

Comment: ¿Este código tiene errores en la consola del navegador?, si es así, edita la pregunta y coloca la descripción del error. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar a tu proyecto la referencia del archivo dataTables.responsive.min.js después del archivo jquery.dataTables.js

jquery.dataTables.min.css

responsive.dataTables.min.css

jquery.dataTables.js

dataTables.responsive.min.js

Comment: Si, esas clases son necesarias. Aparte noté que la tabla necesita clases especificas: <table class="display nowrap dataTable dtr-inline no-footer collapsed">